# View animation only working second time

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I'm trying to make an `ImageButton` slide up and out and then have another set of buttons slide in it's place, my problem is that the second buttons don't "slide" in the first time, only from the second and onward. I tried setting the button containers `Visibility` to invisible instead of gone, but it had no effect of the animation and just split the buttons to the top and bottom of the parent view.

xml

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/user_email_show"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        android:layout_gravity="fill"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:onClick="showEmail"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_email" />+

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/user_email_container"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/user_email_add"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
                            android:onClick="addEmail"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/user_email"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/user_email_input"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="gone">

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/user_email_edit"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
                                android:onClick="editEmail"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/user_email_delete"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:backgroundTint="#FFF"
                                android:tint="#a7a7a7"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/user_email_hide"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#FFF"
                            android:onClick="hideEmail"
                            android:tint="#a7a7a7"
                            android:padding="15dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Show animation method

```
public void showEmail(View view) {

    findViewById(R.id.user_email_hide).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (emailCheck == true) {
        emailTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emailInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        addEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    final Animation slide_up_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up_in);
    Animation slide_up_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up_out);

    showEmail.startAnimation(slide_up);


    slide_up_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            showEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            emailContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            emailContainer.setAnimation(slide_up_in);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

animation file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="150%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: where you call showEmail method

Comment: @sasikumar on the `user_email_show` button